# Wrapper div background wont grow past initial browser window size

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, trying to get the basic skeleton of my design to enable me to add content and have it grow the div to the length of the content. My problem is that it seems that as soon as the page loads, it only shows the background color of the div for the initial browser window size.. I'm not doing a very good job explaining; honestly because I'm not sure what the problem is, I just know it isn't working correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you have floated elements inside of `#fauxcolumns` that you're not clearing. The solution is to clear them.

The easiest way is to add overflow:hidden to `#fauxcolumns` like this:

```
#fauxcolumns {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
```

This question shows other clearing methods if you want to see options:
[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

You also don't need to have `height:100%` on everything, and definitely not on `#fauxcolumns` as it will clip content that's below the "fold".

Comment: new year's resolution... type faster ;)

Comment: That definitely fixes it, but I want the entire page to scroll to actually display that third row with the white background of the wrapper; which is what I'm having trouble with :/

Comment: ? `overflow:hidden` will let you do that. can you show us what you are seeing?

Comment: It does for me if I remove `height:100%` and add `overflow:hidden` to `#fauxcolumns`.

Comment: Ah, just took out the height:100% 's and now i have the third row, thanks Luke! :) now time to research the overflow property so this doesn't happen again..

Comment: Research clearing floats and clearfix methods. Overflow really has little to do with it :)

Comment: Ah, you added the 100% height bit. I guess my answer is a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2):

In `#fauxcolumns`, you declared `height: 100%`. Any time elements use a percentage value, it's relative to their container. Thus, setting `height: 100%` on `#fauxcolumns` results in a height that is equal to the height of the browser window. That is *partially* why your div cuts off where it does. Removing `height: 100%` is the first step towards allowing the height to grow to the size of the content.

The other reason why this doesn't work is because you have floated elements inside `#fauxcolumns` that you haven't cleared. I don't particularly see any reason why you need them floated in the first place, but if you do, adding `overflow: hidden` will ensure that your [floats are cleared](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) and the container wraps these elements.

To summarize, remove this `height: 100%` declaration and add `overflow: hidden`.